# Stop Cordova console logging

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I just upgraded to Cordova 2.0.0 from 1.8.1 for iOS and console logs for the file access are killing me. I am loading a huge text file using cordova file api and cordova is trying to log each line to the console in XCode. This was not the case in earlier versions. Thanks to default logging mode in this new version, I cannot even stop XCode!!

Is there a way to stop or tame the cordova logging?

Comment: You should really raise an issue on JIRA for this one sounds like a bug. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just did: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaz is looking at a fix but the workaround for now is to set your scheme to Release. By default it is Debug which will be verbose like what you have seen.